# Some sprite renderers in a for loop not changing in OnValidate()

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using `OnValidate()` to help me speed up my design process. In the code below (which is in `OnValidate()`), if strictly one enemy has a weapon and the weapon is a sword or spear I change the Sprite for all enemies (the are of type Blue). I am having two issues:

1. The sprite renderer doesn't change until I run the Application though the code is in `OnValidate()`
2. Even when I run the application, not all Sprite Renderers for enemies change. I checked the number with a `Debug.Log`, which prints the right number, but I consistent number of Sprite renderers don't change.

   ```
   if (enemies.Count (x => x.hasWeapon) == 1) {
   if (enemies.Count (x => x.weaponType == Enemy.WeaponType.Sword) == 1) {
       for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
           if (enemies [i].enemyType == Enemy.EnemyType.Blue) {
               Debug.Log (enemies.Length);
               enemies[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/greenEnemy");
           }
       }
   }

   if (enemies.Count (x => x.weaponType == Enemy.WeaponType.Spear) == 1) {
       for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
           if (enemies [i].enemyType == Enemy.EnemyType.Blue) {
               enemies[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/blueEnemy");
           }
       }
   }      
   }
   ```

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Can you please confirm that your folder is set up with the Resources folder like so:
Assets/Resources/Sprites/greenEnemy

Comment: @ryemoss yes the path is right. 4 out of 7 enemies change to the new sprite always, while the remaining sprites never change

Comment: Is there anything different about the 3 enemies that don't change in the inspector prior to running the App? If you move the Debug directly into the for-loop, does it print 7, seven times? I also noticed you check for Enemy.EnemyType.Blue in both statements, should one of these be Enemy.EnemyType.Green? Your code seems fine otherwise.